# How to load up multiple blob images form MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, image, jpeg, blob

I need to load up blob images so i can use them in a slideshow plugin. I need image in a tag. I not sure but how that could be done with the a header, i have only seen example with one picture not more than one. Also note this is all in php.
The header a am talking about is..

```
header('Content-type: image/jpg');
```

If anyone generally know how to load multiple blob images or looping out all blob images in a table please reply.

Answer (score 1):

**Images are meant to stay on disk!**

It's a very bad idea to place them in a DB as you'll have to feed them dynamically through PHP. IF they were on disk, you send them as static files just by using the right URL. PHP would not be involved, database will not be involved also!

**This is how you do it:**

- you create images with special URLs `<img src="/load/image/1234.jpg" />`
- use use a **URL rewrite** like `.htaccess` or `web.config` and capture traffic to `^/load/image/([0-9]+)\.jpg$`
- in PHP you extract the numeric value of the `ID`
- you use the `ID` to locate the blob in the database
- you output the blob to the browser with the right `header('Content-Type: image/jpg');`

^ **but this is a terrible idea regarding your site's performance**. You should loop your DB, save blobs as publicly accessible image files, store the image paths in the DB and use that to generate URLs to static files.

Comment: i cant save the images outside the database I keep getting a error file upload error concerning permissions.

Comment: @user2174767 So setup your permissions right! I use Windows but afaik 0755 is good enough.

Comment: @user2174767 Then I guess you got a bit more learning to do. To tackle something like this, you need to know some stuff...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Data Uri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) to provide multiple images in one request.
More info in this [article](http://www.cdnconnect.com/demos/grouped-image-requests)

It is good idea to cache those DB images. You can use any caching server [varnish](https://www.varnish-cache.org/), [squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) even nginx.

Comment: you can do an ajax call, then insert it to dom